# Magento Database Connection Error?

Tags: mysql, magento, nginx, centos, php

Im attempting to install Magento v1.7CE on CentOS 6.4 with NGINX + PHP5-FPM + MySQL PERCONA

I Manualy created the database and gave the user webmaster ALL PRIVILEGES

Magento Installation Wizard is throwing database connection error im pretty sure the credentials are correct.

Comment: It will be hard to help can you check the error log may be the ip may not be whitelisted if you are accessing from outside

Comment: Having the specific error text would help users track this down.

Comment: thanks guys it was exactly that! which is quiet weird as i am accessing it locally (NGINX+MySQL on same server) a GRANT ALL...TO'user'@'%' that and explicitly defining the IP and port of the database in magento installation wizard did the trick